# Enable the search syntax options for tabs filter

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

I can write the following search query:

> [wix*] and -[wix] is:question

But it is currently not possible for a tab filter. It would be great to have the same syntax being possible in there. Or, alternatively, there can be an option to open the search result in a tab and save it.